# nodejs api data print to web page instead of console

Tags: node.js

```
/*server.js*/
 const http = require('http');

const hostname = '127.0.0.1';
const port = 3000;

const server = http.createServer(function(req, res) {

  res.statusCode = 200;
  res.setHeader('Content-Type', 'text/plain');
  res.end('Hello browser, heres my data: ');


});

    server.listen(port, hostname, function() {
    const Fortnite = require("fortnite-api");

    let fortniteAPI = new Fortnite(
    [
        "email",
        "password",
        "apikey",
        "apikeyserver"
    ],
    {
        debug: true
    }
     );




    fortniteAPI.login().then(() => {
    fortniteAPI
        .getStatsBR("username", "pc")
        .then(stats => {

    console.log('Number of Duo quo wins' + stats.group.duo.wins);

        })
        .catch(err => {
            console.log(err);
        });

});
  console.log('Server running at http://'+ hostname + ':' + port + '/');

});
```

I'm wondering how would I go about requesting the data from stats and print it onto the webpage instead of the console. Any help would be appreciated. More help with the proper syntax if you give an example would also be nice!

Answer (score 0):

If you need to handle a request to your server from the webpage, inside this request get data from fortniteAPI and return it as a response to the user, you can try something like this

```
const server = http.createServer(function(req, res) {
    const Fortnite = require("fortnite-api");
    const fortniteAPI = new Fortnite(
        [
            "email",
            "password",
            "apikey",
            "apikeyserver"
        ],
        {
            debug: true
        }
         );

    fortniteAPI.login().then(() => {
        fortniteAPI
            .getStatsBR("username", "pc")
            .then(stats => {
      res.statusCode = 200;
      res.setHeader('Content-Type', 'text/plain');
      res.end('Number of Duo quo wins' + stats.group.duo.wins);
            })
            .catch(err => {
                console.log(err);
            });
    });
```

As you can see, I've just moved code that connects to the fortniteAPI into request handler. It should work, but without understanding your business it's hard to say if it's what you really need.
Anyway good luck, nodejs is cool enough to go deeper )

Comment: Appreciate the response. It seems to give me an unexpected end of input on line 35(end of the code) however i tried fixing it but when I did and I run the server it just ends the server connection and doesn't actually display anything

Comment: It was not working code for server, but just example how code should be organized, sorry for that. what do you mean "ends the server"? It should work like this: you are starting the server, opening any client (browser or postman), making request to the server and getting expecting response. Have you tried this flow?

Comment: I mean when I run Node Server it just ends without actually displaying the resulting page.